# Laravel Failed to open stream: Permission denied for Dompdf lib fonts permission on CentOs7

Tags: laravel

I created laravel project that work fine on my local windows pc. Once I upload to Centos7 server(via SSH). I have problem on dompdf file export. I got an error
'fopen(/var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/1efc692e8d059670778f16e902f6d711.ufm): failed to open stream: Permission denied'. Picture of errror https://ibb.co/ZShGG2X

This is error message grabbed from laravel.log

```
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'fopen(/var/www/...', '/var/www/html/s...', 45, Array)

#1 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/AdobeFontMetrics.php(45): fopen('/var/www/html/s...', 'w+')

#2 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/TrueType/File.php(361): FontLib\AdobeFontMetrics->write('/var/www/html/s...', NULL)

#3 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FontMetrics.php(212): FontLib\TrueType\File->saveAdobeFontMetrics('/var/www/html/s...')

#4 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Stylesheet.php(1537): Dompdf\FontMetrics->registerFont(Array, 'http://110.49.7...', NULL)

#5 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Stylesheet.php(1376): Dompdf\Css\Stylesheet->_parse_font_face('font-family: 'T...')

#6 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Stylesheet.php(329): Dompdf\Css\Stylesheet->_parse_css('@font-face {\n\t ...')

#7 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php(650): Dompdf\Css\Stylesheet->load_css('\n\t\t@font-face {...', 3)
```

Much appreciated for all advice, Thanks.

Comment: Make sure `/var/www/html/srp` location is owned by web server user. In CentOS it should be `apache` (if Apache server is used; in Ubuntu it is `www-data` for example). Check answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58157/what-is-the-equivalent-for-www-data-for-centos).

Comment: Hi Tpojka, Thank you.